# Modal fade in bootstrap auto add padding-left 15px. Can't change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

When there is little data, no scroll bar appears, everything is normal. But when I add more data, modal auto add `style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;"`:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="tags_modal" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;">
```

I try change it but I can't. 
My code: https://jsbin.com/fusinoc/1/edit?html,css,output

Photo my layout

[image]

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: better if the code can be seen on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: My problem is resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259203/cant-change-css-modal-bootstap-modal-fade-in-bootstrap-auto-add-padding-left-1