# Can't change css modal bootstrap. Modal fade in bootstrap auto add padding-left 15px

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I created this question but there is no answer. so i recreated.

I use modal bootstrap. When no scroll bar appears, everything is normal. But when I add more data, modal auto add `style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;"`:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="tags_modal" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;">
```

I try change it but I can't. 
My code: https://jsbin.com/fusinoc/1/edit?html,css,output

My layout:
[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxKze.png)

Comment: so basically you want to hide scroll bar in modal and the left padding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding styles inline, add below code in your css.

```
#myModal2 {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

working [bin](https://jsbin.com/bifomas/edit?html,css,output)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: wow. I tried it but failed. I tried it again and it works fine. Probably the problem from the cache. thanks so much!!!!